# Angular how to change a 2 state component to a multi-state component

Tags: angular

*I am not as good YET with Angular as other languages.

I need to clone an existing 2 stage Card Component and make it 3+ stage Card Component.  This is what I am starting from:

```
<div [routerLink]="navigationString" [ngClass]="{'card-complete': markComplete}" class="row card-border">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <i class="card-icon" [ngClass]="iconName"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="col-8 card-title">
        {{title}}
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="markComplete" class="col-2">
        <i class="bi bi-check card-icon"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-none d-sm-block">
      <div class="col-md-12 card-description">
        {{description}}
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Component is put on a page it is being set as follows:

```
      <app-card [markComplete]="appointmentStatus?.paymentDate !== null" iconName="bi bi-cash-coin" navigationString="/bill-pay" title="Pay Bill" description="This is where you can pay your balance or co-pay."></app-card>
```

The condition evaluates True or False setting the css class I believe.
But this is setting the [markComplete] on the page that is being used in the component.

To make this a three stage I created a new component and added an @Input() status: string = "";

I've heard two ways to do this but I'm not sure which is right or exactly how to do them.  One direction was on the page itself to simply put [ngClass]="function that returns a css class", but I'm not sure I understand how or if that sets the class on the top level div in the component?  Would I just remove the [ngClass] in the component all together?

Another direction was to use *ngIf against an Enum, but I'm not sure I understand how to execute that approach.

I feel like I'm making this harder than it needs to be, can someone put me on the right path?

Comment: You can consider using ngSwitch (if you want to show different elements), or create a function that would choose the style (eg. inside OnInit or directly from the template).
Check this link: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/using-ngstyle-in-angular-for-dynamic-styling (paragraph "Template expression context")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about adding different classes to the same div, based on some condition right, you can do it quite a few ways.
These are some of the ways:

```
1) Way 1 (Dont forget to add single quotes for the classNames)
<section 
   [ngClass]="{'class1':condition1, 'class2': condition2, 'class3':condition3}" 
> 

2) Way 2
<section
    [class.class1]="condition1"
    [class.class2]="condition2"
    [class.class3]="condition3">
</section>

3) Way 3 (using component.ts and component.html)

// In component.ts : Its a getter method
get customCss() {
    //Logic here;
    if(condition1){
        return 'class1'
    }
    if(condition2){
        return 'class2'
    }
    if(condition3){
        return 'class3'
    }
//// You can keep on adding classes here and keep the HTML pretty clean

}
<!-- HTML -->
// Since its a getter method, you need not put the round paranthesis around the customCss Method;
<div [ngClass]="customCss">Your Content</div>
```

Comment: In way 1 and 2, you are doing that on the actual page html or on the component html?  Because its the page that will know the conditions?

Comment: If I use this, what do I do with the *ngIf="markComplete" div with the checkmark icon in it?  It's in the control itself.  I'm not sure what to make the if try and evaluate within the context of the card control itself?

Comment: the common component.html

Comment: Everything finally clicked for me yesterday!  THANK YOU!  Your answer didn't just solve my problem, it helped me fundamentally understand Angular better!

Comment: Glad I could be of some help @jrandomuser :-)